# Rendering a Django HTML template to a PDF using the primary key for just one object in the model

Tags: django, django-views

I have a model that I want to generate a detail view for to create a PDF and can not seem to get it working to render just one object from the database using the primary key from the request. I think it has something to do with how I am generating my data variable in the view. I can get the PDF to create but I can't seem to get the details to render for a single object.

my code

views.py

```
class GeneratePdf(DetailView):
    model = Runs


    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        runset = Runs.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        data = {
             'runset': runset, 
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf('Runs/pdf.html', data)
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

pdf.html

```
<p>{{ object.run }}</p>
<p>{{ object.driver }}</p>
<p>{{ object.truck }}</p>
<p>{{ object.trailer1 }}</p>
```

render to pdf function

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template

from xhtml2pdf import pisa

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

Comment: You're doing a few things wrong and/or strangely. `DetailView` has an inbuilt method called `get_object`. Try and use this instead of your `runset = Runs.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))`. Try and get a normal Django html template working for the detail view and then convert that to a PDF.

Comment: thanks very much I will look into it.